# Error while loading shared libraries: libdb_cxx-4.8.so

Tags: libraries

I'm trying to execute a program but got the error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libdb_cxx-4.8.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to find out how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you get this program? How did you install it? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try and locate it first

```
 find ~ / -name *libdb*
```

ldconfig  creates  the  necessary  links  and  cache to the most recent
 shared libraries found in the  directories  specified  on  the  command
       line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf

```
 apt-cache search libdb

 apt-get install libdb5.3++-dev libdb++-dev libdb5.3-dev libdb-dev && ldconfig
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the predefined environmental variable in Linux/Unix which sets the path which the linker should look in to while linking dynamic libraries/shared libraries.

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/list/of/library/path"
```

The LD_PRELOAD allow an extra library not specified in the executable to be loaded:

```
 export LD_PRELOAD="/list/of/library/path"
```

ldd checks the (so) shared library files for any missing dependencies

```
 ldd  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.3.so
```

if you're installing it with a package use:

```
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-cxx
```

Comment: Thank you, man! Unfortunately I'm too low to add a point for you but u really helped me!

Comment: it's my pleasure, you're welcome